# Java Application CPU Spike and Memory Leak Over Remote Desktop When Screen Locked

Tags: java, windows-7, memory-leaks, cpu-usage, rdp

I have a Java application that I am running on a computer (COMP-A). I have another computer (COMP-B) that I use to remote into COMP-A using Microsoft Remote Desktop in order to use that Java application. Both computers are running Windows 7. Whenever I am logged in, the application behaves normally using ~200 MB of memory and ~3% of my CPU. The problem is when I lock the screen. The CPU usage of said Java application immediately spikes up to ~20% and the memory leaks nonstop (I got it >1.8 GB, but stopped it at that point as to not crash the system). The System process also seems to increase in CPU usage when the screen is locked as well. Has anybody experienced something similar before? Did you find a solution?

When using COMP-A to look at the java application, locking the screen does not increase memory or CPU. Only difference is RDP. I will try to add logging as a poster had recommended, but if anybody knows of any setting in Windows 7 or RDP perhaps that might be conflicting with Java (AWT) applications, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you could add some logging to see where your application is looping.

Comment: What's strange is similar behavior was seen with JConsole, which is a java application that comes with the JDK. The CPU and memory usage of JConsole also increased when screen was locked. That leads me to believe it's not an issue with my application.

Comment: The only thing we can help you with here is a potential problem with your application.  I'd go ahead and try the logging; it does not necessarily follow that, because some other application is experiencing the same problem, that it's not a problem with the application.  Both applications could have the *same* problem.

Comment: Don't use "Edit" or "Additional Information" in your posts.  A complete edit history of your post is available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17072967/revisions), for anyone to look at.

Comment: Just to follow up, I submitted a trouble ticket with Microsoft and a bug report to Oracle. Microsoft denies any issues on their end and Oracle has acknowledged that it is a new Java bug (Bug ID: 9004028). Hopefully it gets fixed in a future Java release!